# How do I enter the Aperture Science Innovators initiative?

Tags: portal-2

Hurray! I'm stuck again in chapter 6, after the announcement from Cave. There is a bridge to enter the next section but I'd need to be a TF2 scout to cross it.

There obviously must be a solution with portals; indeed, parallel to the bridge, there's portal-enabled sections on the ground and on the wall opposite; this *screams* of flinging. However, I can't quite pull this fling out.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Place a portal in the blue area on the wall, top left corner
2. Enter slowly, walk over metal structure, take the left corner, stop on wooden plank.
3. Drop off towards the white blocks below, fling through with a second portal
4. Hurl through the portals, smash nose against the Aperture Science logo, or land right above it.
5. Quickload. (GOTO 10)

How am I supposed to set up this jump?

Comment: I got stuck here too, took me long enough to figure it out..

Comment: This was the only part of the game I resorted to a walkthrough for help, just completely missed that angled wall. I actually spent most of my time trying to get into the fenced-off tunnel.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I made it! Here's a visual explanation.

[image]

Comment: Closed captioning for the picture impaired:
1. Portal up to the walkway at the top.
2. Place a portal on the angled piece below you.
3. Jump off the ledge (aiming for the portalable ground surface), dropping the other portal under you. 
4. If this works, you'll fly through the air, through the round logo, landing on the far side.

Comment: On the walkway, there's a board or solid plate at the spot where you need to jump off to the portal-enabled ground.