# How to continue in Chapter 6 The Fall?

Tags: portal-2

I'm at the control room in Chapter 6, but I have no idea how to continue. My first guess is to get across here:

[image]

So I made two portals: one high above me and one right below, so that I would get throw to the other side. But every try ends with a rather unpleasant encounter with the Aperture logo.

[image]

Any suggestions as to how to continue?

Comment: I thought that this was a duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20365/how-to-enter-the-aperture-science-innovators-initiative), they seemed so similar... xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First tip, you're not supposed to go to that exit yet. Take a look around and try something else. You'll know when you're supposed to go up there.

Another hint:

> You should get to the top floor of the office building, you'll find something inside

Solution:

> Portal up to the platform like you did, and then put a portal on the sloped surface at the left of your second screenshot. Jump down from the platform and open a portal on the ground below you. This will catapult you to the upper floor of the office building

The next step after that:

> Now the bridge should be extended and you should be able to jump down from the platform and use that momentum to get to the exit.

Comment: I actually tried catapulting myself onto the building, but it didn't work and I kept focusing on the wrong thing :(

Comment: @IVo At least I hope you did find something in the wrong thing that made it less wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You must activate the elevator in the control room first. No double flinging is required.

[image]

Like so:

[image]

Comment: There is little-to-no double flinging required in this game.  They took out most of the twitch-reflex type stuff.

Comment: @shinrai There's still some in the coop.

Comment: badp - Right, but generally it's your partner flinging you while you're in the air so it's not so bad. :)